# Qutrit analogues of controlled Z and cc-Z gates

Tags: quantum-gate, pauli-gates, quantum-state

I am trying to look for the qutrit analogues of a controlled-Z, and a cc-Z (Z gate with two controls) for qubits.

There is a previous [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/defining-standard-qubit-gates-for-qutrits) that gives a qutrit analogue of a CNOT gate, but does not talk about the gates I mentioned.

Note that controlled-Z is a Clifford gate. So, it is expected any qutrit analogue should also be a Clifford gate.

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16401/10480

Comment: Look at the qudit formulation of the stabiliser formailsm. There are tons of papers, e.g. one by Gottesman from 1999 http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9802007 ...

Answer (score 4):

Based on the paper [*Elementary gates of ternary quantum logic circuit*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5485), the extensions of the Z gate are as follows

$$
\begin{gather}
Z^{[0]} = \text{diag}\{-1, I_2\} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
Z^{[1]} = \text{diag}\{1, -1, 1\} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
Z^{[2]} = \text{diag}\{I_2,-1\} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
$$

The controlled variant, denoted $TCZ$, is defined as the gate that implements $Z^{[n']}$ on the target qutrit iff the control qutrit is in the state $|n\rangle$ where $n\in\{0, 1, 2\}$. Figure 3 (a) below gives the circuit representation of the $TCZ$ gate.

[image]

However, as noted in the comments by @unknown, this gates are not Clifford. For a Clifford formulation of the $Z$ gate, we can turn to [*Canonical forms for single-qutrit Clifford+T operators*](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eneilr/Papers/Qutrit.pdf) that defines it as

$$
Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \omega & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \omega^2 \end{bmatrix},
$$

with $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 3}$ which means $Z^3=I$. To convert this into a qutrit controlled-$Z$ operator, I recommend taking a look at [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16412/16092) answer, taken from a question linked in the comment to your original question.

Comment: Is there a way to see that this gate still remains a Clifford gate? The qutrit extension of the Hadamard gate, as mentioned in that paper, is not a Clifford gate.

Comment: I doubt that they are Clifford. The process to check if $CZ$ is Clifford or not is the same as for the Hadamard gate but now the Pauli group involved is of order $3*9*9=243$ and the matrices are $9x9$. Note that $Z$ above are not of order 3; so even these don't look like natural generalization of qubit $Z$ gates.

Comment: @unknown what do you mean by *$Z$ above are not of order 3*? I've expanded the matrix representations in my answer for clarity.

Comment: @BlackHat18: as stated in the other comment, I think this generalization of $TCZ$ is not a Clifford a gate, but it is what I've found most in literature.

Comment: @epelaaez the matrices are of dimension 3 ($3x3$) but order 2 not 3. So $Z^2=I$; the most "natural" generalization of qubits to qutrits defines $X^3=I, Z^3=I, X'Z'XZ=wI, w^3=I$

Comment: @unknown ah ok, sorry for the confusion there. So, probably what the OP is looking for is the definition [here](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~neilr/Papers/Qutrit.pdf) that gives $Z = \text{diag}\{1, \omega, \omega^2 \}$ where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/3}$.